# Needing to sort by x axis date 'period'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've tried multiple ways to get the dates to sort earliest to current, but I'm unable to do so. I figure it has to be something simple that I'm overlooking so I'm reaching out for assistance.

I'm still new when it comes to matplotlib, python, and python. I really do appreciate the assistance this community has shown me.

I've broken the date time out into month and years so I can create a column for period. I'm looking to sort the total saves per period from earliest to most current.

```
ausers["period"] = ausers['year'].astype(str)+' '+ ausers['month'].astype(str)

atime = ausers.period.value_counts()
atime.plot(kind='bar')
plt.title('Successful saves by month')
plt.ylabel('Number of saves')
plt.xlabel('month')
```

Currently I have the chart as it needs to look but I can't get it to sort number of saves by period.

I'm thinking perhaps I need to re sort my period so I have the month first?

Comment: Maybe you should work with `year` and `month` combined as `datetime`, e.g. `ausers['periods'] = pd.to_datetime(ausers['year'].astype(str)+' '+ ausers['month'].astype(str))`.

Comment: ok, I'll run through the attempts I made previously with them as a datetime. @QuangHoang do you have any tips on how to remove the 00:00:00 from the graph that gets added when converted to datetime?

Comment: Thanks for the format assist Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in order to sort anything related to date, I'd maintain the "date" datatype first for the correct ordering.

**Convert the original column to datetime (before you've separated into Year/Month columns)**

`import pandas as pd
ausers["Period"] =  pd.to_datetime(ausers['original_date_col'], format='%Y:%m')`

- This will add `'Period'` to your df and convert your `date_col` to datetime for easy sorting.
- by setting the format parameter to `'%Y-%m'`, the output will be something like `2019-08`

**Then sort the df:** 
`ausers = ausers.sort_values(['Period'])`

Hope this helps/provides value :)

Comment: So I formatted the datetime as you said but I still get the day and the timestamp making the sort legend just a black overlap of words. how do I trim the datetime output?
The sort works great though
I appreciate the help on this

Comment: To trim the datetime output, the "format" parameter of `to_datetime` needs to be fixed/changed. I'm guessing it's going right down to the nanosecond. We want to end with just the Year - Month. `"%Y - %m"` should do it. If not `"%Y - %b"` may work 

Documentation - https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior